# Puppeteer timeout cleared on waitForNetworkIdle

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, puppeteer

Im trying to call waitForNetworkIdle twice but when seconds call it throws me an Timeout cleared Error.

Heres the following function that im trying to call twice

```
private async clickEnterButton() {
    this.logger('Clicando em entrar')
    await this.page.waitForSelector('#submit-button')
    await this.page.click('#submit-button')
    await this.page.waitForNetworkIdle()
}
```

I have tried to use waitForNetwork outside the function, tried to change node and puppeteer version.

Comment: Had the same issue with v20.7.2. See https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10398#issuecomment-1595692536, which suggests that this is a bug and was introduced after 20.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use this function and wait for something real.

(wait for submit button not to exist, for example)

Waiting for network idle it's last variant when you don't have proper condition that should be resolved after action.

I'm sure there can be proper response you can handle in this case

```
await page.waitForResponse(res => res.url().includes(someUrl);
```

or proper element that is rendered after form completion.